# GoogleMaps SDK ios install with Cocoapod error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm recently learn iOS and I want to install the GoogleMap SDK for iOS in my project.

But when I installed with `pod install` it got an error say that the 'GoogleMaps' doesn't have concrete dependency ... or some thing like that.

I did as the instruction on the GoogleMapsAPI web source and this is my Podfile

`'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'GoogleMaps'`

Please tell me where do I did wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a target for each pod.

e.g. if before you had your Podfile written like this:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

just change it to

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target "TargetName" do
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with latest `pod` you need to write `Target` in `Pod file`

Like below.

Currently your pod file looking like

```
pod "YOUR_POD"
```

Change To

```
target "Your_Target_Name" do
     pod "YOUR_POD"
end
```